# Auto refresh XML RSS file using http-equiv="refresh"

Tags: php, xml, rss, refresh

I created an XML file for RSS feed using PHP, its header like below:

```
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
```

I need to make the page refresh every 120 seconds

I can make any HTML or PHP page auto refresh using :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120" />
```

How can I add the previous refresh code to my XML RSS code?

Comment: Why? RSS is intended to be consumed by feed reading software which will poll it on a schedule automatically.

Comment: To which RSS specification is your question connected? [RSS 2.0](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html)? If so, can you please point out where such a *"refresh code"* is part of that specification? I have problems to locate it ...

Comment: @hakre — If the OP could find such a thing then they'd have answered their own question.

Comment: @Quentin I need to grab only 5 posts each 120 , and I need to make refresh to update my facebook page using new 5 posts or old 5 posts depends on my code

Comment: @hakre my Rss is 2.0 `<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">`, my Rss has no refresh, but I want to add `http-equiv="refresh"` to it or to its header so it can auto refresh every 120 seconds

Comment: @usamasulaiman — How would reloading a page cause facebook content to be updated? You'd need to use Facebook's APIs to push or pull the data on your timer, not use something intrinsic to the document.

Comment: @usamasulaiman: You do not need to add something. You can just refresh your own each 120 (or the many you like) seconds. Just press F5 each time you want to refresh or if that is automated, just HTTP request the XML  again.

Comment: @Quentin I told you, that depends on my code, simply I have an application which take my Rss feeds and upload it automatically to my Facebook page

Comment: @usamasulaiman — So run your application every 120 minutes then.

Comment: so why people using PHP ? sure to do automatically what they don't want to do manually, right? I am doing every thing automatically just by writing the perfect php code

Comment: So run your program automatically using cron or something. You can't put something in the data that will make the program run (not unless you write your program to look out for that data, and keep the program running all the time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy free way to do refresh for me, it's a Google chrome application - even I'm normally using Firefox - but I think I can use chrome for that task

[Easy Auto Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc)

It can Auto-refresh and auto-reload pages after any number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to make the page refresh every 120 seconds

Well, I doubt that partially because there is no page here. Page (and the later used term *"refresh code"*) would imply that HTML is involved (the *"HTML page"*), however no HTML is involved. Per the Content-Type you set XML - not HTML - is involved:

```
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
```

As XML and not HTML is involved, no HTML is involved and ergo there is no such HTML refresh (the atrribute value *http-equiv* might mislead you that a *refresh* header would be HTTP but it is actually not part of the protocol, so you probably were mislead by that construct, see [*Meta Refresh*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)).

So you might need to do that, but technically spoken, this is not possible. Or to say it the other way round: Only you need something it must not mean that you have formulated your need well enough to find what you need.

> How can I add the previous refresh code to my XML RSS code?

You could add it verbatim - for example inside an XML comment - however I suppose you ask how you can add such functionality that is comparable to a webbrowser and a HTML page having that code.

Well good question. As this is an XML feed that you serve from your server it is just requested. You could send some caching and revisit-after information via the HTTP response headers ([Caching in HTTP - RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13) is covering that topic extensively) but apart from that, I do not know about any other side-channel to pass some kind of refresh information with RSS.

As RSS is XML based and therefore modular you can suggest and extension to do so and then tell the vendors of the software that are considered to work with your XML feeds. That's perhaps most easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to refresh a RSS feed displayed in a *browser window*, just send an `HTTP`header with the same contents as the `http-equiv` `<meta>`element (that's all  this element does: convey some data that normally would be sent using `HTTP` headers), like:

```
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");
header("refresh: 120");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
```

Be aware that this *not* Standards conform, since it's an addition introduced by Netscape and has never been standardized. But it *should* work in most browsers.

If that's *not* what you want and you just want to tell the client when to revisit the feed for updates use `<ttl>` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0"><channel>
  <title>RSS Title</title>
  <!-- other meta data here ... -->
  <!-- time the information in this file stays valid (when to refresh) in minutes: -->
  <ttl>2</ttl>
  <!-- rss items, here ... -->
</channel></rss>
```

As detailed in: https://cyber.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#ltttlgtSubelementOfLtchannelgt